# Is there a brightness switch for the AOA gauge on the F-16?

Tags: avionics, cockpit, f-16

Is there a brightness switch for the AOA gauge on the F-16? Please share a picture with the panel if you can.

Comment: I made some edits to hopefully make your question a little more clear. If I got it wrong, please just roll back or edit again!

Comment: Could the users who downvoted this explain the reasons behind their decision? If the original wording was poor, it's useful to remember that not all users' native language is English. In its current, edited form, I see nothing wrong with the question – so even if the reason was poor wording, I believe you ought to remove the downvote now. Aviation Stack is one of the few non-elitist Stacks out there, and I'd like it to remain that way.

Comment: George's questions seem to attract minus votes because of language barrier. That is just wrong guys, don't be an ass and slap -1 when you don't understand what someone is asking, help 'em out! The main function of this site is to answer questions, not rate them, and definitely not downvote for no good reason. If the Q does't belong here, is totally beyond repair or unclear, vote to close or report it. We rate the A to higlight the best ones and drop the ones that miss the point or are just wrong. Upvoting a Q means you are interested too, but you do **not** downvote simply because you are not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The F-16's manual is declassified since it's in service in [many countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:F-16_operators.png).

### AOA Indexer

The answer is yes, the switch (lever) is conveniently located on the gauge. From said manual:

> **AOA Indexer**
>
> (...)
>
> A dimming lever, located on the left side of the indexer, controls the intensity of the lighted symbols.

And here's a photo from [airliners.net](https://www.airliners.net/photo/Belgium-Air-Force/General-Dynamics-SABCA-F-16AM-Fighting-Falcon-401/2394136) (red arrow):

> [image]

### AOA Indicator

In case you mean the AOA indicator on the instrument panel (yellow arrow above), then no, it doesn't have its own separate lighting. It will be the instrument panel light switches aft of the flight stick.

> [image]
> Source: [airman.dodlive.mil](https://airman.dodlive.mil/2018/02/12/f-16-fighting-falcon/); click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwLtA.png) for the switches schematic (first two rows)